# Using old toolbars in Excel 2010 and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, excel-2010, toolbars

I have a toolbar with some actions linked to macros in Personal.xls. I want to use the toolbar in Excel 2010 under Win7, but it insists C:\Documents and Settings\user\App...\PERSONAL.XLS doesn't exist. Quite right, they've changed the %AppData% location to C:\Users\user... And I can't put a copy of PERSONAL.XLS in the old place because C:\Documents and Settings\ is special-cased in Windows 7, and it's a forbidden place to everyone.

My question: How can I reset the macro linked to the toolbar buttons?

You used to be able to access

- the Commandbars collection to get a command bar
- The Controls collection of the command bar to get a control (button in this case)
- The OnAction property of the control to identify the linked macro.

But OnAction doesn't seem to be a supported property for Excel 2010.

Any suggestions?

I'd much rather relink the toolbar than create a new custom ribbon tab. The toolbar buttons don't waste the APALLING amount of space custom ribbon items take up, and the custom icons on my toolbarare meaningful. Subsiduary question: Are there simple ways to create custom designs for custom ribbon items?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I didn't investigate closely enough. "OnAction" might not appear in the Object Browser, but it is available, and can be used to reset the associated toolbars. It didn't seem to work using the Immediate window, but does work within code in a module.

Cheers folks...